# x86 Assembly segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, std, att

I can compile it but when I run it I get "segmentation fault".
Would love if someone explained why.

```
.section .data
digitformatstr: 
.string "%d\n"

.section .text
.global main

main:
    push    $1337
    pop     %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    push    -4(%ebp)
    push    $digitformatstr
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp
```

Comment: You're using `ebp` as a pointer, but I don't see you initializing `ebp` to point to a valid address anywhere.

Comment: Where would I do that? :/ I feel confused

Comment: @FelixRabe What do you want `%ebp` to point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using GNU assembler and GCC's C Library to build your executable. The primary problem with your code is that you don't set up register *%ebp* before using it. Typically with `C` your function sets up the local stack frame first which includes initializing *%ebp*. To properly set up the local stack frame, and cleanup the stack before returning you could use code like this:

```
.section .data
digitformatstr:
.string "%d\n"

.section .text
.global main

main:
    push    %ebp           /* setup local stack frame */
    mov     %esp, %ebp

    push    $1337
    pop     %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    push    -4(%ebp)
    push    $digitformatstr
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp

    leave                  /* remove local stack frame */
    ret
```

A beginner's guide to the stack frame and 32-bit C calling convention can be found [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html).

One other comment about your code. You do:

```
    push    $1337
    pop     %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    push    -4(%ebp)
    push    $digitformatstr
    call    printf
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with this code. It almost appears you were trying to place 1337 on the stack as a local variable (but space hasn't been allocated on the stack for local variables). Since it appears you are trying to simply call `printf` where the second argument is an integer, you should just push that value (1337) on the stack. All the code above should simply be:

```
    push    $1337               /* 2nd argument to printf */
    push    $digitformatstr     /* 1st argument to printf */
    call    printf              /* call printf
```

The final cleaned up code for `main` could look something like:

```
main:
    push    %ebp            /* setup local stack frame */
    mov     %esp, %ebp

    push    $1337           /* 2nd argument to printf */
    push    $digitformatstr /* 1st argument to printf */
    call    printf          /* call printf
    addl    $8, %esp        /* cleanup the 2 32 bit arguments */
                            /* we pushed on the stack */

    leave                   /* remove local stack frame */
    ret
```

Comment: Worked pretty good! Thou after the code is done I get segmentation fault :o It prints properly and everything.

Comment: added call exit at the bottom and now it seems to work, Thx again :)!

Comment: The above code should work with `leave` and `ret` without using a call to `exit` unless you are somehow building your program different than I expected. If you added to your question the command(s) that you use to compile and link I might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: @FelixRabe I didn't actually look closely to all the code you have written. I have fixed another bug that could cause issues (it is how you were trying to pass 1337 to printf).